# Swift to objective-c translation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to implement code written in Swift to see if it'll achieve what I want it to in my already-made Objective-C project but I'm having trouble trying to translate/re-word it to Objective-C.

Here is the code in swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
    var feedContent:String! = "<h3>\(selectedFeedTitle)</h3>\(selectedFeedContent)"
    myWebView.loadHTMLString(feedContent, baseURL: nil)
} 

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "openWebPage" {
        let fwpvc: FeedWebPageViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FeedWebPageViewController
        selectedFeedURL =  selectedFeedURL.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString:"")
        selectedFeedURL =  selectedFeedURL.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString:"")
        fwpvc.feedURL = selectedFeedURL
    }
}
```

I already changed the the `override func` to `-(void)` and the `super.viewDidLoad()` to `[super viewDidLoad];` and it is accepting that with no error but it's giving me errors for a few more lines in that code. I looked for translation tips online but still cant get them to work.

Comment: They are two different languages. You really need to learn Objective-C to be able to translate this. You might start looking for code samples implementing viewDidLoad and prepareForSegue and go from there. Note: super.viewDidLoad() is [super viewDidLoad];

Comment: Question lacks specificity, has not been adequately researched, and generally does not fit into Stack Overflow. Please refine it further, and show a stronger research and development effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should translate to something like this (not tested in an actual IDE):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
    NSString *feedContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<h3>%@\</h3>%@", selectedFeedTitle, selectedFeedContent];
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:feedContent baseURL:nil];
} 

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"openWebPage"]) {
        FeedWebPageViewController *fwpvc = (FeedWebPageViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        selectedFeedURL = [selectedFeedURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        selectedFeedURL = [selectedFeedURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
        fwpvc.feedURL = selectedFeedURL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does Objective-C has string interpolation like Swift? `NSString *feedContent = @"<h3>\(selectedFeedTitle)</h3>\(selectedFeedFeedContent)";`

Comment: @ZoffDino It doesn't. I blindly pasted the string without looking at it. Next time, be my guest and edit my answer instead of dropping a smart comment.

Comment: You own your answer. I don't feel like editing other people's answers is a good idea.